# Controller with some synchronous and some asynchronous actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

Is there a way to have a controller with some synchronous and some asynchronous methods on it? I have one action that would benefit from using an asynchronous model, but I don't want to drag the rest of the actions with it if I can help it.

So far the only way I've seen to do MVC async is to change the whole controller to an AsyncController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid question I guess. Looks like you can just put synchronous actions on an AsyncController.